# How to get Div id while click the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <div id=ControlId>
<span>Select Option</span> 
</div>
  </div>

   <div id=ControlId + "_child"  style="display: none" > 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> option 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> option 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" /> option 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

i have added above more than one time in td's  like following image

[image]

how to achieve id for main div in click event , actually my issue was if i click first div , finally added only opened

```
$("#" + ControlId).click(function () {
    $("#" + ControlId + "_child").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#" + ControlId + "_child").toggle();
});
```

this  is my actual event code

Comment: Where is the Javascript variable `ControlId` defined? Also, remember that ID attributes need to be unique, so if you have the above multiple times, you'll need to increment a counter or something to ensure they are unique.

Comment: i'm increment the counter . Event fired for last added one

Comment: i'm increment the counter then only using , i have added my coding inside loop only , if i click first one , still opened last added Div

Answer (score 1):

try this
html

```
    <div id="select1" data="select">
    <span>Select Option</span>
</div>
<div toggle="select1" style="display: none">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
                option 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />
                option 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" />
                option 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="select2" data="select">
    <span>Select Option</span>
</div>
<div toggle="select2" style="display: none">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
                option 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />
                option 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" />
                option 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data="select"]').click(function () {
            var selectdiv = $(this);
            $('[toggle]:not([toggle="' + selectdiv.attr('id') + '"])').hide();
            $('[toggle="' + selectdiv.attr('id') + '"]').toggle(); ;
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: how to close div . while open another div ?

Comment: add this line "$('[toggle]:not([toggle="' + selectdiv.attr('id') + '"])').hide();" check i have update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
$("#" + ControlId).click(function () {
    $("#" + this.id + "_child").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#" + this.id + "_child").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of id give class for div

```
     <div id="ControlId" class="ControlId">
      <span>Select Option</span> 
      </div>
    </div>


 $(function()
 {

$(".ControlId").click(function()
 {
 var div=$(this);
 //hide or toggle child divs

 });
});
```

Comment: this one also i have tried i get same result , Please try like controlid was integer variable i have incremented . add more than one time , not working for me